# Distance between two charged particles

Tags: electromagnetism, distance

Is there a way I can find a function $r(t)$ that gives me the distance that separates a charge $q$ and another charge $Q$ knowing the initial velocity of both $v_{01}$ and $v_{02}$ and the initial distance $r_0$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are these *point* charges? Same sign charges? And what are the directions of $v_{01}$ and $v_{02}$?

Comment: yes they are point charges, but not of the same sign and the direction of their initial momentum is along the radius vector but could have different magnitudes.

Comment: The electrostatic attraction force is given by Coulomb's Law, Use it to set up a system of two equations of motion ($F=ma$) from which $x_{01}(t)$, $x_{02}(t)$ and thus $r(t)$ can found.

Comment: But $a$ changes over time and doesn't even vary in a polynomial way. Or maybe do I have to solve a second differential equation by setting $a=d^2x/dt^2$

Comment: Yes, like I wrote: two equations, one for each charge. It's not a simple problem. It could be simplified if charges and masses are the same. Symmetry then tells you $a_1=a_2$.

Comment: Please edit the question. It is too broad. Should we take into account the magnetic effects caused by the motion of the charges?

Answer (score -1):

This is two body system. In such case you should make the following change of variables $\bf r=\bf r_1-\bf r_2$ and $\bf R=\frac{m_1 \bf r_1+m_2 \bf r_2}{m_1+m_2}$. It corresponds to center of mass system
In such case the Lagrangian has the simple form:
$$L=\frac{m_1\dot r_1^2}{2}+\frac{m_2\dot r_2^2}{2}+\frac{q_1 q_2}{|\bf r_1-\bf r_2|}=\frac{(m_1+m_2)\dot R^2}{2}+\frac{m_1m_2\dot r^2}{2(m_1+m_2)}+\frac{q_1 q_2}{r}$$.
Thus variables are separated. The variables $\bf R$ corresponds to motion system as a whole and variables $\bf r$ corresponds to relativity motion of two bodies. It means that equation of motion on $r$ is equal a motion of one particles with mass $\frac{m_1m_2}{m_1+m_2}$ in the field $U=-\frac{q_1 q_2}{r}$. It is a Kepler problem.

Comment: I don't think this is right. Coulomb law only works with static charges. If the charges are moving then there is going to  be a magnetic field that would affect the other charge, and of course they are going to radiate energy so... nah!, this is wrong.

Comment: I was discuss no relativistic problem, where $v/c\ll1$. In such case $B \sim E \frac{v}{c}\ll E$, where $E$ and $B$ is a characterize value of the electric and magnetic field.